# Is there an easy-to-follow tutorial to learn Craft CMS basics?

Tags: templating

I am thinking about using Craft CMS for building multiple websites for my organization. A friend recommended Craft CMS, but I am finding it very hard to get started, unlike GRAV, which was very easy to install and use.

I am looking for a tutorial that steps users through the building of a simple website from A to Z and in the process explain why Craft CMS should be given more consideration over other tools.

I looked online only to find a few such tutorials, but you have to pay to access them. I am in the evaluation phase and do not want to pay for something that I might not use.

If anyone knows of a good and comprehensive tutorial, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Craft has an official getting started tutorial now! https://craftcms.com/docs/getting-started-tutorial/

**Original Answer:**

---

Welcome to Craft!  Here's a collection of developer resources to help get you up to speed on Craft quickly.

The most important thing to note about Craft CMS and Craft Commerce is that they are platforms used to build bespoke solutions for clients. They are light on traditional "out of the box" features and instead invest heavily on providing developers with a modern toolset and content teams with a great author experience. In practice this means that every Craft site is made specifically for the client which is great and what clients and developers appreciate about it. The downside is if you are brand new to Craft and have no context to the original build out or developer, it can be a challenge to get up to speed.

**Craft Official Docs & Support**

- [Craft CMS docs](http://craftcms.com/docs) - Pretty comprehensive and worth reading if you're new to Craft.
- [Craft Commerce docs](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/introduction)
- [Craft Slack group](http://craftcms.com/community#slack) - All of the Craft dev team is on Slack every day with 5,000+ other Craft developers and users from all over the world.
- [Craft StackExchange](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/) - You'e obviously found this one, but this is the best place to ask "how do I" implementation questions.

**Learn Craft**

Free and commercial.

- [Mijingo Craft's Tutorials](http://mijingo.com/craft) — Mijingo is an official Craft education & training partner. They have a number of excellent free and paid resources for Craft & Craft Commerce. Ryan Irelan, Mijingo's founder, also offers customized training online or on-site.
- [Tuts+ Tutorials](https://tutsplus.com/courses/search/Craft+CMS) — Not official but very good and low cost (most are $9).
- [Craft Straight Up Hangouts](https://straightupcraft.com/hangouts) — Hosted by Ben Parizek, these are live learning sessions with Ben and a member of the Craft team.
- [Studio 107 Blog](https://nystudio107.com/blog) — Andrew Welch is a prolific Craft developer and the creator of the [SEOMatic plugin](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic). He has some excellent developer-oriented posts on Craft that are worth reading.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I am finding it a challenge to get started, but will take a look at some of the resources that you have listed and see where that takes me. I might go with GRAV for now until I develop a good understanding of Craft CMS. I am hearing a lot of good things about it and would like to give it a try, but want to take my time to learn it well. I think that Craft CMS can significantly increase adoption of the technology by providing a really good Getting Started guide that connects all of the pieces together.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing a "build a favorite board games library" in Craft CMS 3 tutorial.

Outline:
Setting up local development, cover Craft's building blocks, import data, create front-end templates, style it with Tailwind CSS & deploy to a server.

The first 4 lessons are up:

1. [Craft CMS 3 Local Development with Lando Docker](https://www.eaglepeakweb.com/blog/install-craft-cms-3-lando-docker)
2. [Create a Board Games section in Craft CMS](https://www.eaglepeakweb.com/blog/create-board-games-section-craft-cms-tutorial)
3. [Import board game data into Craft CMS](https://www.eaglepeakweb.com/blog/import-board-game-data-into-craft-cms-feed-me-tutorial)
4. [Style Board Game Cards with Tailwind CSS](https://www.eaglepeakweb.com/blog/style-board-game-cards-tailwind-css-craft-cms-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

Craft CMS offers scalable, secure content management and presentation platform. Craft CMS has ditched the traditional CMS systems that come with pre-built themes, CSS frameworks, and ready-to-go page templates In Craft CMS you can build anything on your own and customize solutions with a combination of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

These are the main free resource links to learn about Craft CMS from beginner to expert level.

1. https://craftcms.com/docs/getting-started-tutorial/#why-craft-cms
2. https://craftquest.io/lessons

Answer (score 0):

Jeroen Kenters' YouTube video called "Migrating a website to Craft CMS for Beginners" was extremely helpful for me. Assuming you know about the other languages involved (HTML and CSS), it's a great quick-start guide. He also goes over how/where to find things on the Craft and Twig documentation sites.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3BO5EP05qs

Comment: Note, as of 19 November, 2020, this video is set to private and cannot be viewed.