# How to create website using Craft CMS

Tags: craft-features

How to create website using Craft CMS admin Control Panel. I want to create a single home page using Entries, Section, Fields, Category, Assets, Tag.

Comment: Full flow for add and check in browser.

Comment: My changes of entries and sections are not reflecting in web-page.

Comment: It's a bit of a broad question for a direct answer, but there are some good learning resources in this link: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/22191/57

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have any templates. You first need to have templates that render the info you are editing in the admin panel. [In this section](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/twig-primer.html), templates in CraftCMS are introduced, you may also want to refer to Twig, which is the template engine used in CraftCMS.

From your questions I am guessing you are (I may be wrong) new to web development. If you want to learn more about web development you should go with HTML5. When you know HTML5, you will be able to code your own templates in Twig.

If you **just want a single page** you should use something less powerful than CraftCMS, I think that creating a [**github personal page**](https://pages.github.com/) for yourself is the fastest, easiest and more fascinating way for a beginner.