# Is it possible to add a Section, Entries in basic/simple HTML page instead of Twig template?

Tags: templating, craft3

In Craft CMS is it possible to add a Secion, Entries in basic/simple HTML page instead of Twig template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a Section in Twig either. You have to use PHP in order to create logic. Html is only used to display things on you page but it does not include logic nor is it able to fetch elements (working with databases) Twig is a template engine, you could describe it as a middleman between HTML and PHP it is able to fetch elements and uses a limited amount of PHP to display them

You won't be able to work with Craft properly without using Twig at all unless you modify many things with PHP

Like mentioned in the other thread Craft might not be the correct  CMS for you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but it generally doesn't make much sense because the purpose of CraftCMS, is to allow anybody to easily change the content of what is in the template without having to use actual HTML.

If you want your template to be plain HTML, you can do so by creating an HTML file under the `templates/` folder and pointing to it in your section settings. For example, for `templates/terms.html` you'd set your section template as:

[image]

**Note:** Did you have the chance to read [my answer here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26187/how-to-create-website-using-craft-cms/26189#26189)? Do you have any questions about what I said?